# locks turns into float and unable to trace it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vHBb6X5SbC/

This is my code. I'm writing an Multiprocess download lib.
However, it output like this:

```
['59.48898033500149%', '18.16582379395445%', '65.49106789861011%', '23.566474111076044%', '81.36570670954329%', '52.62770077964777%', '19.65509403291828%', '14.561298847451326%', '43.26657356330367%', '26.08677759239945%', '10.633553162271985%', '40.582614011764456%', '0.016365607021580585%', '24.15154456209755%', '5.42929012940936%', '14.135792500093295%', '31.20154110228526%']
[0.5950125454002246, 0.18194463606242217, 0.6551152490738709, 0.23582839718097626, 0.8138616371832026, 0.5262770077964777, 0.19671459639939864, 0.14561298847451326, 0.43266573563303673, 0.2608677759239945, 0.10633553162271986, 0.40582614011764456, 0.00016365607021580586, 0.2415154456209755, 0.05433381531164755, 0.1416852371282868]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Project\ArcaeaLib\ArcaeaLib.py", line 1343, in <module>
    a.run()
  File "c:\Project\ArcaeaLib\ArcaeaLib.py", line 235, in run
    if self.lock[n].locked():
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'locked'
```

The second list is my self.lock, which I used it in thread():

```
self.lock[num] = _thread.allocate_lock()
with self.lock[num]:
```

and I didn't modify it anywhere. But now, it turns into float.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [mcve].